# jQuery call to function not working

Tags: jquery, function

I'm trying to clean up my jQuery code a bit and I'm doing that by definen functions in my code, but I'm pretty new to it so I ran into a little problem

```
    function appendToContent_vragen() {
    $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').appendTo('#content_vragen');
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').css({overflow : 'hidden', color : 'black'});
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeIn(400);
    });
}

$('#geregeld , #niet_geregeld').on('click','.container_vragen').click(appendToContent_vragen);
```

The problem with this code is that the click function doesn't work. If I do it like this

```
$('.container_vragen').click(appendToContent_vragen);
```

It does work but it selects the wrong .container_vragen (since it's not in the #geregeld , #niet_geregeld div.

Here's a jsFiddle of the whole project. On the top is the function.

Comment: jsFiddle seems down for me.

Comment: Post your html markup here

Comment: its very difficult to understand when you are not showing relevant code or put it somewhere

Comment: Without more code, it's very hard to see what is going wrong. Tip though: you can merge those 3 lines $(this).closest into 1 line; 
`$(this).closest('.container_vragen').appendTo('#content_vragen').closest('.container_vragen').css({overflow : 'hidden', color : 'black'}).closest('.container_vragen').fadeIn(400);`
If you do a $(this) 3 times, jQuery has to re-select your element on every iteration, chaining (like my example) will speed it up, as the element is only selected once.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nu4YH/ Here's the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This line should be line:

```
$('#geregeld , #niet_geregeld').on('click','.container_vragen').click(appendToContent_vragen);
```

Should be like this:

```
$('#geregeld , #niet_geregeld').on('click',function(){
    $('.container_vragen', this).click(appendToContent_vragen);
});
```

Correcting the answer:

```
 $('#geregeld , #niet_geregeld .container_vragen').on('click',appendToContent_vragen);
```

Comment: This method seems to work but I have to click on the .container_vragen element twice for it to do the function appendToContent_vragen

Comment: I'm afraid that this method does not react to the on click in the element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to select children after a jquery element selector

```
$('#geregeld , #niet_geregeld').children('.container_vragen').click(appendToContent_vragen)
```

Comment: Sounds logical but the click does not call the function.

Comment: what prints when you console.log() the selector? is the click being bound to the right element?